How do I determine whether the order of items in a container type is arbitrary?
Some containers in C++ are intentionally well-ordered, e.g. std::list, std::vector or std::map (and even std::deque, although one could question whether it has one order or two equally-valid orders). Other containers - aren't, like std::unordered_map. And of course, this goes for containers which we may define ourselves, outside of the standard library.
Still, such containers are iterable: You can go from std::begin(my_container) to std::end(my_container) - and that is an order, somehow, on the elements of the container.
Is there a type trait, or some other mechanism, which I might use in a function template taking a container type, to determine whether the order of items in the container is meaningful, intentional, inherent - or whether it is just an arbitrary, accidental, ephemeral implementation detail?

Notes:

Any C++ language version would do, the earlier the better.
I suppose this question applies to ranges as well, but I'm mostly interested in actual containers.
I'm (mostly) ignoring the stability of the order and of iterators under addition/removal operations.


Couldn't fint a good tag regarding the ordering of data, that does not involve sorting :-(

What exactly do you mean by "well-ordered" ? a std::map is definatly ordered by a key (and typically implemented via a tree). But a std::vector and std::list is just a sequence of elements that could be in any order value-wise.

Could you give an example of where it would be useful to know this programmatically (instead of just by reading the docs)?

@NateEldredge: Only a bit abstractly, but - if I'm writing a templated function which takes a container and positions or offsets into that container - which would be used on the order-during-iteration of items - I would like to assert that these positions or offsets are a legitimate thing to use with that container.

Why not write a custom trait?

@einpoklum "positions or offsets" implies random access iteration, right? Or you mean directly taking std iterators? There are some awkward cases like std::priority_queue, which is ordered, but can't be iterated out of the box.

@Xellos: No, it doesn't: Items in lists have positions and offsets-of-positions.

The only ordered types ar set and map and their new flat counterparts. The rest follow insertion order.

@einpoklum You can't access elements in std::list by position, only by the inefficient way of iterating i times (just like set/map), in which case you might as well give an iterator - that's why I ask if you want to use iterator as argument.

@Xellos: Of course I can access them by position, it's just not O(1).

I'm not sure if you're looking for a predefined trait, but if not, here's an idea:
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
// etc

template<typename T>
struct is_ordered_container;

template<typename T, typename Alloc>
struct is_ordered_container<std::vector<T, Alloc>> : std::true_type {};

template<typename Key, typename T, typename Hash, typename KeyEqual, typename Alloc>
struct is_ordered_container<std::unordered_map<Key, T, Hash, KeyEqual, Alloc>> : std::false_type {};

// etc

int main()
{
  static_assert(is_ordered_container < std::vector<int> >::value);
  static_assert(!is_ordered_container < std::unordered_map<int,int> >::value);
}


So, your suggestion is to define my own. That is one of my fallback strategies, true, but it's not really what I asked...
